# List of all colors available for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am searching for a list of all colors I can use in PowerShell. Since we need to provide names and no hexnumbers, it's hard to figure out if a color exists or not, at least if you don't know how :))

For example, as `-foregroundcolor`

```
write-host "hello world" -foregroundcolor "red"
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The console colors are in an enum called [System.ConsoleColor].  You can list all the values using the GetValues static method of [Enum]

```
[Enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor])
```

or just

```
[Enum]::GetValues([ConsoleColor])
```

Comment: Just expanding on mjolinor's code:[Enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) | foreach { Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor $_}   This will display all the names of the colors in the said color

Comment: In PowerShell 5-7 I had to use: [System.Enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) | foreach { Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor $_}

Answer (score 103):

Pretty grid

```
$colors = [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor])
Foreach ($bgcolor in $colors){
    Foreach ($fgcolor in $colors) { Write-Host "$fgcolor|"  -ForegroundColor $fgcolor -BackgroundColor $bgcolor -NoNewLine }
    Write-Host " on $bgcolor"
}
```

[image: screenshot of colourful output]

Updated colours in newer powershell:

[image: screenshot of colourful output]

https://gist.github.com/timabell/cc9ca76964b59b2a54e91bda3665499e

Comment: This code shows very well that DarkYellow actually isn't that dark and neither very yellow. Is this a bug?

Comment: `DarkYellow` and `DarkMagenta` background look very different (but correct) in powershell 6.1+.

Answer (score 27):

I've found it useful to preview how the console colors will display with a simple helper function:

```powershell
function Show-Colors( ) {
  $colors = [Enum]::GetValues( [ConsoleColor] )
  $max = ($colors | foreach { "$_ ".Length } | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
  foreach( $color in $colors ) {
    Write-Host (" {0,2} {1,$max} " -f [int]$color,$color) -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$color" -Foreground $color
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

How about checking the help? Like so, `get-help write-host` will tell you:

```
[-BackgroundColor {Black | DarkBlue | DarkGreen | DarkCyan | DarkRed | DarkMagenta | DarkYellow | Gray | DarkGray | Blue | Green | Cyan | Red | Magenta | Yellow | White}]
[-ForegroundColor {Black | DarkBlue | DarkGreen | DarkCyan | DarkRed | DarkMagenta | DarkYellow | Gray | DarkGray | Blue | Green | Cyan | Red | Magenta | Yellow | White}]
```

Comment: I used the get-gelp for forgroundcolor and that brought me to powershell profiles. thank you anyway

Answer (score 9):

I'm not going to write down all ~7million ([which you can apparently use now](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/) if your terminal can display them), but here are the main ones, [all named for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting)
I've included other things like "`bold`", `underline`, and `negative`.

Just call them like this (`fg` for `foreground`, `bg` for `background`, and `bf`/`bg` for "bright" foreground/background. `default` to reset and there's `fg.default` + `bg.default` too for resetting those individually)

```powershell
$style.fg.green + 'Im green!'
'I feel a little ',$style.bg.black,' moody' -join ''
"Math is pretty $($style.negative)$(191 * 7)$($style.default) too"
```

[image: COLOURS!]

Those 24-bit colours a aluded to? `$style.bg.rgb -f 120,32,230`. Maybe you're running pwsh on linux or come from a 'nix background? `$style.fg.x -f 30` xterm colours will make you feel at home.

```powershell
#console colours (VT escape sequences)
$style=@(
    0, 'default', 'bold',
    4, 'underline',
    24, 'nounderline',
    7, 'negative',
    27, 'positive',
    '_fg',
        30, 'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white',
        39, 'default',
    '_bg',
        'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white',
        49, 'default',
    '_bf', 90, 'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white',
    '_bb', 100, 'black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white'
) `
| &{
    Begin {
        $sequence="$([char]27)[{0}m"
        $style=@{
            fg=@{
                rgb=$sequence -f '38;2;{0};{1};{2}'
                x=$sequence -f '38;5;{0}'
            };
            bg=@{
                rgb=$sequence -f '48;2;{0};{1};{2}'
                x=$sequence -f '48;5;{0}'
            };
            bf=@{};
            bb=@{};
        }
        $current=$style
        $index=$null
    }
    Process {
        Switch -regex ($_) {
            '\d' { $index=$_ }
            '^_' { $current=$style[$_ -replace '^.',''] }
            Default {
                $current[$_]=$sequence -f $index++
#comment me out
"$($current[$_])$($_)`t" | Out-Host
            }
        }
    }
    End {
        $style
#more demonstrations
@(($style.bg.rgb -f 120,32,230), ($style.fg.x -f 30), 'hello', $style.default) -join '' | Out-Host
    }
}
```

Apparently you can set hyperlinks and truncated text too!
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7744

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work at all in powershell 6.1.1 on Win8.1.

Comment: sorry, `5.1.18362.752` (build `10.0.18362.752`) on Win10 here

Comment: I've read the linked material but somehow, I fail to see how to achieve what I want. I'd like to *Write-Host -ForegroundColor ???* so that the text is e.g. pink. In fact, I'd like to specify my personal triple of integers to use a custom RGB color. It seems that your answer suggests it's possible but I haven't grasp the how-to of it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of displaying all color combinations of background and foreground colors.

```
$FGcolors = [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor])
$BGcolors = [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor])

Foreach ($FGcolor in $FGcolors)
{
    Foreach ($BGcolor in $BGcolors)
    {
        Write-Host ("Foreground: $FGColor BackGround: $BGColor")  -ForegroundColor $FGcolor -BackgroundColor $BGcolor
    }
}
```

Comment: The output can be compacted, for quicker visual scanning: `Write-Host "$FGColor on $BGColor " -background $BGColor -foreground $FGColor -nonewline`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to be that hard.  Tab completion is your friend.  Pressing tab after `-foregroundcolor` (or any unique abbreviation) will list them.  In emacs edit mode, they will all list at once.

```
set-psreadlineoption -editmode emacs  # put in your $profile

write-host hello world -f # press tab, it actually appears above it

Black      Cyan       DarkCyan   DarkGreen   DarkRed    Gray      Magenta    White
Blue       DarkBlue   DarkGray   DarkMagenta DarkYellow Green     Red        Yellow
```

It's also in the docs under `-Foregroundcolor` (and `-BackgroundColor`):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7#parameters

Answer (score 2):

In case you come here from Google and want to know what color names are available in Windows, you can do:

```
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationFramework; [System.Windows.Media.Colors] | Get-Member -static -Type Property |Select -Expand Name
```

(Notice how you first need to load the `PresentationFramework` assembly.)

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
Black
BlanchedAlmond
Blue
BlueViolet
Brown
BurlyWood
CadetBlue
Chartreuse
...
```

Only some of these are printable by their *name* in the Powershell Console, although the new console supports "all" (24-bit TRUE) colors, through the ANSI color escape sequences and when `VT` has been enabled.(`VT` = *Console Virtual Terminal Support*)

To get a list of the (`Write-Host`) printable names, you can do this:

```
# Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationFramework
$colors = [System.Windows.Media.Colors] | Get-Member -static -Type Property |Select -Expand Name
Foreach ($col in $colors) { try { Write-Host "$col"  -ForegroundColor $col -BackgroundColor Black } catch {} }
```

[image]

To get a **full list** of all the Windows *defined* color names, you can run this magic:

```
function argb2box { $c = ($args[0] -split '#..(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})'); $r,$g,$b = ("$c" -join(' ')).trim() -split ' '; return "`e[48;2;$([Int32]"0x$r");$([Int32]"0x$g");$([Int32]"0x$b")m    `e[0m"; }
$sc=[System.Windows.Media.Colors]; $sc | Get-Member -static -Type Property |Select -Expand Name| ForEach { [pscustomobject] @{ ARGB = "$($sc::$_)"; MEOW = $(argb2box "$($sc::$_)") ; Color = $_}}

# You can sort on HEX values by adding:
# | sort -Property ARGB
```

[image]

[image]

---

You can read more about this here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#screen-colors
- https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/7479/friday-fun-with-powershell-and-ansi/

Comment: **UPDATE**: Apparently the *PresentationFramework* is not available until the *GetTypes* method has been executed, so in order to do that we have to add the `-PassThru` like this: `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework -PassThru | Out-Null`. See [discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16054).

Comment: LOL, I didn't come here for this, but now that I've seen it I can't stop thinking about it.

Comment: **UPDATE-2:** Apparently the *PresentationFramework* is problematic these days. Instead you may need to load the *PresentationCore* instead, using: `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore -PassThru | Out-Null` **and/or** using: `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$PSHome\PresentationCore.dll").GetTypes() | Out-Null`. I have no idea what is happening there.⁉️