# How can I see the Current Color Scheme in Windows Terminal (Powershell Core) itself?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

I have set a custom colour scheme in Windows Terminal. Now I want to see all the values with their colour from Terminal Itself. Is there any way to see it.

Like for eg.
I have set colour code #000 for black.
Now If there is any command that can show all the colour scheme values FOR eg: black, red with their color black and red(like syntax highlighting).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41954792/11942268) answer your question?

Comment: Does windows terminal have an object model like $psISE in the powershell ise?  Another option would be parsing the json settings file.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, Thomas!